# Sample IBM MFP Java adapter causes an error on import. FWLSE2302E Malformed ziped content

Tags: java, maven, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

After downloading the sample java adapter from the MobileFirst Operations console I tried to import it and received the following error:

> FWLSE3051E: Invalid payload. See additional messages for details.
>
> > FWLSE2302E: Can't read the content: failed to extract data from the zip format. Malformed ziped content.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to your-mfpserver:9080/mfpconsole/index.html#/downloads#samples and click on the ["Hello World" link](https://git.ng.bluemix.net/imfsdkt/console-samples/raw/master/javaAdapter.zip) under "Java Adapter Samples".
2. Save javaAdapter.zip to disk.
3. Navigate to your-mfpserver:9080/mfpconsole/index.html#/mfp/browseAdapters
4. Click "Actions"->"Import Adapter"
5. Click browse, choose the javaAdapter.zip you saved to your disk.
6. Click deploy.

We're using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation Operations Console
Product version: 8.0.0.00-20170710-1834

I'm just trying to get the simplest adapter to work, so I thought I'd start with "Hello World", then I discovered this doesn't even work.  I was developing java adapters 6 months ago just fine and using maven to deploy or create an .adapter file.  In the meantime, we upgraded versions of MFP and now it appears only a .zip file is acceptable, but I can't find a working example.

How can I resolve this issue?  I wasn't responsible for the configuration or installation of MFP and don't know too much about it.

Comment: I think the .zip is meant to be used with 'mvn install' though this fails too. _Could not find artifact com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-api:jar:8.0.2017102609_

Comment: I have had some success by taking an earlier adapter, using `mvn install` to create a _.adapter_ file, then creating a **specific** zip and importing.  I'm still getting an error, but it's a different error.  The important thing is that the _.adapter_ file resides in a zip that has a single **adapter** directory with a single **adapterPackage** directory that contains only the **[adapter-name].adapter** file in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample app needs to be built (a detail I overlooked when asking the above question) and a .adapter file needs to be created.

The larger issue is the **Malformed ziped content.**(sic) error.

Solve this by creating a directory named **adapter** containing a single directory named **adapterPackage** that contains only the **.adapter** file in it.  Then zip the contents and you can utilize the MobileFirst Operations Console to import this zip (Actions->Import Adapter).

---

e.g. **myAdapter.zip** should contain **adapter->adapterPakcage->myAdapter.adapter**

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload  zipped adapter file,you should deploy the .adapter file .
Follow below steps

1.Unzip  adapter and open in a terminal 
2.run command 'mfpdev adapter build' 
3.run 'mfpdev adapter deploy ' or you can deploy it via console Click "Actions"->"Import Adapter choose .adapter file .

Please see here for more details

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/android/

Comment: As I noted in my comment above, I realized it requires a build.  This didn't work, however.  The larger issue I was really trying to resolve was the "Malformed ziped content."(sic) error. I contributed an answer below.